# I'm making a codename one app with geofencing but it seems to stop calling back after it's gone into the background for a while

Tags: codenameone, geofencing

I'm working on an app using geo fences but I'm hitting some issues.
I've been testing on Android predominantly so far.

a) I set up the geo-fence and it triggers fine for enters and exit events.
However, after an extended period time (such as a few hours or overnight) the events stop until the app is opened again.

b) My other issue is the geo-fence exit seems to trigger even when I haven't moved at all, and definitely not outside of the radius (150 meters).

I've looked at https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/location/Geofence.html, and my code is very similar to the example.
Are there any other build hints I need to make it more accurate and persist in the background?

Comment: Which Android version are you using? Are you adding geofencing every time or just once (saving whether geofence was added before)

Comment: We've tried it on a number of devices with mostly Android 6 (6.0.1 on the two I've just checked).  
I'm adding the geofence whenever the app is run.  
Should it only add it on the first run, and cache in storage if its been done?  
Or are you saying I need to re-add this when it's triggered?

Answer (score 1):

Geofencing should only be added once, it's a very flaky API in the native OS especially when it comes to background behavior that breaks frequently with OS updates.

Use something like:

```
if(Preferences.get("AddedGeofence", false)) {
    addGeofenceBinding();
    Preferences.set("AddedGeofence", true);
}
```

And see if this works.

Comment: Hi Shai, I have tried this but Geo fencing is still getting killed in the background

Comment: We're looking at improving geo fencing on Android, it seems this is a victim of some Google changes so we might take a different path for this functionality

Comment: I'm not versed in this but code that used to work stopped working probably related to the battery improvement work they are making. We generally need to rewrite portions of our native code related to geofencing on Android